# psexec works on local machine but nothing happens on remote machine

Tags: c#, asp.net, remote-server, psexec

I tried to psexec to remote machine. It works perfectly when I type `psexec \\192.168.180.148 -u xxxxx -p xxxxx net localgroup Administrators testuser /add` to my cmd in local machine, `testuser` was added into Admin group on remote machine. But when run through this c# code nothing happens.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C psexec \\192.168.180.148 -u xxxxx -p xxxxx net localgroup Administrators testuser /add";
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: This question is about ASP.NET. Please do not add unrelated tags.

Comment: Why do you execute psexec through `cmd.exe`? Why not execute `psexec` directly? Furthermore, I think there's a SysInternals licence agreement that pops up first time you use `psexec` - could that be the case here? Try adding `-accepteula` to the arguments.

Comment: I added `-accepteula` and it still didn't work

Comment: Out of curiously - is this code running from ASP.NET (I see it was removed by someone) in IIS? If so the `asp.net` tag should be `restored` to this question and be sure your AppPool user account has the rights to run `psexec` remotely. Default AppPool accounts can't do terribly much

Comment: yes, I run this code from ASP.NET in IIS. Don't know why John remove the tag. But anyway, I think if I can run those command from my cmd and it works perfectly, then I also can run it through this code. Can you be more specific about AppPool account @MickyD thank you so much

Comment: also you need some rights on machine where psexec is running, it needs to access HKLM:\Security or HKLM:\SAM I'm not sure. So you have to run cmd with other account, `cmd /runas /user:domain\acc cmd.exe` then run psexec.

Answer (score 1):

> yes, I run this code from ASP.NET in IIS.

Default AppPool accounts can't do terribly much even from the perspective of the local computer. Generally they can only access files in the website folder and **not** say `c:\temp`.

`psexec` requires **admin rights** on the *target machine* which most likely the account for your IIS site doesn't satisfy.  To fix this either change how you *launch the child process* *or* *change the account* for your IIS site AppPool as a whole to one that has admin rights on the remote machine.  Reguarding the latter, by doing so will affect your website as a whole so any Windows Authentication-style connections (like to a database) will need to be reviewed.

1. Open *IIS Manager* by typing `inetmgr` at the Windows **Start** prompt
2. Select your server and expand the **Application Pools** node
3. Find your AppPool, right-click and choose **Advanced Settings**

[image]

4. On the **Identity** row, click **...**
5. In the **Application Pool Identity** window, select **Custom account**
6. Click **Set...**

[image]

7. Fill out the fields for the account with admin rights on the remote machine.  If the account is a local account you will need to manually replicate it to the IIS box.  Also check that this account has access to your normal IIS resources like file system folders.

[image]

If you are not sure which app pool your site is using you can find out as per below:

[image]

Comment: can i confirm that `Select your server` is my server remote? And I also stuck at step 7 with error `The specified user name does not exist`

Comment: No, I am referring to IIS computer.

Comment: Then I have an account `user/1234` from group admin in the remote server.I typed that account in Set Credentials (step 7) and it said `The specified user name does not exist`. I think IIS computer doesn't realize that account

Comment: Did you see _"If the account is a local account you will need to manually replicate it to the IIS box"_.  If the account in question is **not** a _domain_ account you will need to recreate the account on the IIS box with the same password as the account on the remote computer.  Remember, this answer is just to get you going